ios carplay implementation without using scene lifecycle
I'm trying to imeplement CarPlay into a legacy Cordova app that uses AppDelegate inernally.
I can't seem to be able doing it as the CarPlay API seems to require UIApplicationSceneManifest while the Cordova app internally does not have one.
As soon as I add the UIApplicationSceneManifest, CarPlay works, however my Cordova app doesn't display content, it displays black screen instead.
Is there any way around this? Either by implementing CarPlay without using Scene lifecycle, or somehow having the window of the app unaffected when running on the phone?
